# Lookup Local EJB from Glassfish LifeCycle module

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb-3.0, local, lifecycle

I can look up the remote interface of an EJB3 from a Glassfish 2.1 using the global jndi name. However, as I understand, if this were not a LC module but an EJB (Servlet), I would have an *ejb-local-ref* entry in its *ejb-jar.xml* (*web.xml*).

Is there a place to define Local references for an LC module?
Thanks!

Comment: Or alternatively, I would be happy if you showed me a working example of calling a local EJB from a Lifecycle module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the [Glassfish EJB FAQ](https://glassfish.dev.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html#POJOLocalEJB) :

> The EJB spec only requires local ejb access from within the same application in the same JVM.

and

> The EJB Local view is an optimized EJB
>   invocation path that uses
>   call-by-reference semantics.   It is
>   only available to web components and
>   ejb components that are part of the
>   *same application* as the target EJB.   That's why ejb-local-ref is not even
>   part of the schema for
>   application-client.xml.   To access
>   EJBs from an Application Client or
>   stand-alone java client,  you'll need
>   to use either a Remote 3.0 Business
>   interface, a 2.x Home interface, or
>   web services.

The LCM lives outside the application containing the EJB, by definition, so, the answer is no.

When I discovered them, I saw all kinds of interesting applications for LCM's, but as I discovered more and more limitations (the fact that they are GF-specific included) that enthusiasm mostly disappeared.